# How to use clojure doc function?

Tags: emacs, clojure, doc, classnotfoundexception

I'm just starting with Clojure and can't access to the doc function.

I'm using clojure 1.3 with emacs24 and swank-clojure.

```
user> *clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 3, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}
```

But when I try:

```
(doc doc)
```

I get:

```
Unable to resolve symbol: doc in this context
[Thrown class java.lang.RuntimeException]
```

I've read [Why does REPL treat clojure.core/doc as a var?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443922/why-does-repl-treat-clojure-core-doc-as-a-var) and as suggested:

```
(clojure.repl/doc doc)
```

But then, I receive:

```
clojure.repl
[Thrown class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException]
```

It seems I am not "importing" the usual namespaces, but really doesn't know how to do it.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Using clojure from java (java -jar ...) it works well, so it's a problem with the emacs setup.

Comment: `(doc doc)` works fine on my Clojure run as `java -jar clojure-1.3.0.jar`. Did you try to use it this way?

Comment: Yes, using clojure directly from java works well, so it seems it's a problem with my emacs setup. Thanks for answering.

Comment: If you're using SLIME from Emacs, the clojure.repl stuff isn't loaded into your REPL because SLIME itself already provides equivalents - for example, you can get docs with [C-c C-d d](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Documentation.html#Documentation)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to grab the clojure.repl namespace one way or another:

From the REPL

```
user> (use 'clojure.repl)
user> (doc doc)
```

or in your program

```
(ns foobar
  (:use [clojure.repl]))
```

Comment: Nice answer, works for me!  The OP and a comment make me think that it's a version issue -- is this the case?

Comment: Isn't `clojure.repl` namespace automatically used in a repl session? Am I missing something?

Comment: Goran, it depends on how the REPL is started.

Answer (score 16):

Add the following to your Leiningen user.clj file (on Mac / Linux, it's ~/.lein/user.clj):

```
;; ~/.lein/user.clj
(if (>= (.compareTo (clojure-version) "1.3.0") 0)
  (do (use 'clojure.repl)
      (use 'clojure.java.javadoc)))
```

This will cause Leiningen to automatically import those two namespaces at startup for projects using Clojure 1.3.0 and later (but not for projects using Clojure 1.2.1 or earlier - where doc and source were always available).

Credit goes to [Matthew Boston](https://twitter.com/#!/bostonaholic/status/130130333801775104) for this. Note also [Phil Hagelberg's reply](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.clojure.user/52399) which points out most of the REPL-specific functionality is accessible directly in Emacs / Slime without needing the functions directly in the REPL.

Comment: There is a typo in Phil's reply: the correct SLIME docs command is [C-c C-d d](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Documentation.html#Documentation).  (Also, it may save someone some frustration to know that user.clj has been deprecated in recent versions of Leiningen.)

Comment: Running [cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) with `*clojure-version*` `{:major 1, :minor 5, :incremental 1, :qualifier nil}` and only `C-c C-d` is needed to start entering the function name to get help on.  Actually, this was described at the bottom of this [tutorial](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/tutorials/emacs.html) but was prefaced with the older, no longer working, way of getting the doc.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>As of Lein 2, namespaces can be automatically imported at startup using `:injections`, e.g:</strike>

```
;; ~/.lein/profiles.clj
{:user {:plugins [[lein-swank "1.4.4"]
                  [lein-noir "1.2.1"]
                  [lein-pprint "1.1.1"]]
       :injections [(use 'clojure.repl)
                    (use 'clojure.java.javadoc)
                    (use 'clojure.pprint)] }}
```

But see other responses for SLIME equivalents.

I'm unsure of when this became the case, but as of lein 2.2 *doc* is available at the repl by default.